# Removing the edges of UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to make `UISegmentedControl` more so like square and I sense that the edges seams to be more like a troublesome. Would anyone would have an idea as of how can I eliminate these edges to be more white color than the border color?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
segmentContrl.layer.borderColor=*anycolor*.CGColor;
segmentContrl.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
segmentContrl.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html), you can choose between a number of `UISegmentedControlStyle` types, or any of the customisation methods under 'Customising Appearance'.

Customisation is limited, your best bet will be to make your own custom `UIControl` or `UIView` subclass that copies the behaviour of the standard `UISegmentedControl` but is styled as you desire.